# Apache2 not responding to port 80 IPv4 requests

Tags: networking, debian, apache-http-server, dbus

Have encountered a strange problem where my apache2 daemon although supposedly listening according to netstat and lsof is not responding to requests. Here is what I have found so far.

- Ensure port 80 open and apache is listening

```
lsof -I:80
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 6253     root    3u  IPv4 1596968      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6257 www-data    3u  IPv4 1596968      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6258 www-data    3u  IPv4 1596968      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 6259 www-data    3u  IPv4 1596968      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

- Ensure firewall has port open

```
table inet filter {
    chain input { # handle 1
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        ct state established,related accept # handle 4
        ct state invalid counter packets 68 bytes 3278 drop # handle 5
        ...
        tcp dport 80 counter packets 11 bytes 568 accept comment "HTTP" # handle 21
```

- Ensure traffic is coming in on port 80

```
tcpdump -n -I eth0 host 75.119.198.106 and port 80 
16:39:50.317217 IP 75.119.198.106.41804 > 47.220.62.53.80: Flags [S], seq 3381923713, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
16:39:52.333431 IP 75.119.198.106.41804 > 47.220.62.53.80: Flags [S], seq 3381923713, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
16:39:56.461186 IP 75.119.198.106.41804 > 47.220.62.53.80: Flags [S], seq 3381923713, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
16:40:04.653345 IP 75.119.198.106.41804 > 47.220.62.53.80: Flags [S], seq 3381923713, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
```

As you can see traffic is coming in but not being responded to by the apache process.

Looking at the logs in `/var/log/apache2` nothing unusual but in the journal logs when I restart apache with `apache2ctrl restart` I see this:

```
Jul 02 16:19:24 pve systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 02 16:19:25 pve systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 02 16:19:25 pve dbus-daemon[8901]: [system] Rejected send message, 4 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.708" (uid=33 pid=6257 comm="/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start " label="system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0") interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager" member="GetDynamicUsers" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init " label="system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0")
```

This is the only indication of something gone awry and I am not familiar with how this is supposed to work. In my `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.systemd1.conf` the file looks to be intact as I have never touched it until now.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">

<!--
  This file is part of systemd.

  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
  (at your option) any later version.
-->

<busconfig>

        <policy user="root">
                <allow own="org.freedesktop.systemd1"/>

                <!-- Root clients can do everything -->
                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"/>
                <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.systemd1"/>

                <!-- systemd may receive activator requests -->
                <allow receive_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Activator"
                       receive_member="ActivationRequest"/>
        </policy>

        <policy context="default">
                <deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"/>

                <!-- Completely open to anyone -->

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
                       send_member="Get"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"
                       send_member="GetAll"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="GetUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="GetUnitByPID"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="GetUnitByInvocationID"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="LoadUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="GetJob"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ListUnits"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ListUnitsFiltered"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ListUnitsByPatterns"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ListUnitFiles"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ListUnitFilesByPatterns"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="GetUnitFileState"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="GetUnitProcesses"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="GetUnitFileLinks"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ListJobs"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="Subscribe"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="Unsubscribe"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="Dump"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="GetDefaultTarget"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="LookupDynamicUserByName"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="LookupDynamicUserByUID"/>

                <!-- Managed via polkit or other criteria -->

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="StartUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="StartUnitReplace"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="StopUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ReloadUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="RestartUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="TryRestartUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ReloadOrRestartUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ReloadOrTryRestartUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="KillUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ResetFailedUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="SetUnitProperties"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ListUnitsByNames"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="StartTransientUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="CancelJob"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="Reload"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="Reexecute"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="RefUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="UnrefUnit"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="EnableUnitFiles"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="DisableUnitFiles"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="ReenableUnitFiles"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="LinkUnitFiles"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="RevertUnitFiles"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="PresetUnitFiles"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="PresetUnitFilesWithMode"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="MaskUnitFiles"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="UnmaskUnitFiles"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="SetDefaultTarget"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="PresetAllUnitFiles"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager"
                       send_member="AddDependencyUnitFiles"/>

                <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.systemd1"
                       send_interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Job"
                       send_member="Cancel"/>

                <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.systemd1"/>
        </policy>

</busconfig>
```

Comment: Please add output of "iptables -vnL"

Comment: Not using iptables, the pertinent rules for nftables are shown above, port 80 is accepted on WAN input chain.

Comment: I also changed my /etc/apache2/port.conf file to: ```Listen 0.0.0.0:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Add `tcp dport 80 meta nftrace set 1` as the _very first_ rule of your input chain, then run `nft monitor trace` while trying to connect. Note that it is not Apache but the kernel itself that has to respond to TCP SYNs...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the culprit was SELINUX even though I had `SELINUX=permissive` in `/etc/selinux/config`. I switched it to `SELINUX=disabled` and rebooted and all was well once again.